# Erro execução DotNet no Mac

Tags: c#, osx, openssl, .net-core

Boa noite, fiz a instalação do .Net Core conforme instruções:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Criei o diretório do projeto e quando vou executar (via terminal), conforme comando:

```
dotnet new
```

Recebo o erro abaixo:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Native': The specified module could not
>   be found.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)    at
>   Interop.CryptoInitializer.EnsureOpenSslInitialized()    at
>   Interop.CryptoInitializer..cctor()    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at Interop.Crypto..cctor()    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at Interop.Crypto.GetRandomBytes(Byte* buf, Int32
>   num)    at System.IO.Path.GetCryptoRandomBytes(Byte* bytes, Int32
>   byteCount)    at System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()    at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions.TemporaryDirectory..ctor()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.EnvironmentAbstractions.DirectoryWrapper.CreateTemporaryDirectory()
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetPackagesArchiver..ctor()    at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel
>   nugetCacheSentinel)    at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry
>   telemetryClient)    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) Abort trap: 6

Já procurei em diversos fóruns, fiz vários comandos, mas continua não funcionando.

Pode haver alguma coisa relacionado com o `Openssl`?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Só para eliminar dúvidas. Você executou o `dotnet restore` para baixar as dependências?

Comment: Leia posts dessa página: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9171

Comment: Já executei sim @FelipeDonda.

Comment: @DanielOmine, li e fiz os procedimentos informados, inclusive baixei o nuget, porém, o erro persiste da mesma forma.

Comment: Você instalou o `openssl` através do `brew`?

Comment: Sim @FelipeDonda.